Use supabase to back a public API with api key auth
How can I use supabase as a database for a REST API, with some "api key" (something like what Stripe or Twilio does) solution?
I am trying to use supabase as the database backend for a public REST API. The REST API is currently built using Express NodeJS (typescript specifically) and deployed on GCP.
I was hoping to take advantage of supabases's Row Level Security features because I need a multi-tenant architecture for my database - each tenant should only be able access their own data. So for example, for a table Purchases, User A should not be able to see, edit, or access User B's Purchases and vice versa.
However, I'm running into an auth issue - Supabase's auth seems to be written for an application that has a frontend and can do client login/signin, therefore with a JWT that expires pretty quickly. I want to instead use a persistent api key (something like Auth0) to authenticate my user's requests to my API, but I'm not sure how to translate that into something that will honor Supabase's RLS.
I've considered:

Using my service account JWT for requests to Supabase, and including some tenant_id in every table. However, this has the con that every query needs to have WHERE tenant_id = 'tenant_id', which feels brittle and doesn't really take advantage of the RLS in Supabase.
Using the JWT from Supabase as the api key, but typical "sign in" doesn't really work for an API user, and the expiration is too short.

